How to change markers color in 2D plot in plotly with hexcode?
Is it possible to change the color of the markers using the given of hexcode?
Code:
import plotly as px

hydrogen= px.scatter(plot_data,x='Calorific Value (kcal/kg)',y='Hydrogen (%)',title='Hydrogen Plot',
                    width=800,height=800,hover_name='Lab',color='Hexcode')


The goal of my code is to change the color of the markers to its hexcode. I think I have issue to my code. I was trying to do something like this

I want to make my 2d plot like this same hexcode to its marker color.

There is an argument that you can use for the px.scatter function called color_discrete_map which allows you to pass in a dictionary that lets you specify the color that you would want of each value in the plot.

thank you for respond. But I am working with 300+ hexcode and specify each of the color of the markers can cause a lot time. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Yes you can do it.
Suppose your data have three columns x, y and color (in hex code).
The following code have been tested to give the desired output. feel free to test it.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def generate_random_hex_color():
    return "#{:06x}".format(random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))

# Parameters
num_points = 100

# Generate random data
data = {
    'x': np.random.rand(num_points) * 100,  # Random x values
    'y': np.random.rand(num_points) * 100,  # Random y values
    'color': [generate_random_hex_color() for _ in range(num_points)]  # Random hex colors
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], c=df['color'], alpha=0.7, edgecolors='w', s=100)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Scatter Plot with Random Colors')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

The result of this code is illustrated in the following plot screen
